# Port forwarding with encryption

Tags: encryption, tcp, tunneling

I am searching about 2 months for a port forwarder with encryption and this is making me almost crazy.
I tell my goal and maybe someone can help me:
I want to forward socks5 packets to another server and make it secure (safe from sniffing) because my ISP parses the socks packets and also blocks some packets. now, I want an open source (rather python, javascript[node], mono, perl) or easy to use command line tcp forwarder with encryption and decryption to forward socks packets to another server.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The program [spiped](http://www.tarsnap.com/spiped.html) can do what you are asking:

> spiped (pronounced "ess-pipe-dee") is a utility for creating symmetrically
>   encrypted and authenticated pipes between socket addresses, so that one may
>   connect to one address (e.g., a UNIX socket on localhost) and transparently
>   have a connection established to another address (e.g., a UNIX socket on a
>   different system).  This is similar to 'ssh -L' functionality, but does not
>   use SSH and requires a pre-shared symmetric key.

https://code.google.com/p/spiped/source/browse/trunk/README

https://github.com/morgante/spiped-docker